# How Can You Combine Rotate and Grow On Hover Into One CSS Animation With a Fixed Axis?

Tags: html, css, animation

I want both animations to execute on hover and then reset back after the cursor moves away like the rotate animation I have below.  So I just need to combine the grow animation with a keyframe or ?  Any Suggestions? Thanks.

```css
#rotating_image {
                position:absolute;
                left:70px;
                top:100px;

                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
                transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
                
                }

#rotating_image:hover {
                      transform:rotate(360deg);
                      -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
                      -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
                      }
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZKEqcWm.jpg" id = "rotating_image">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale), also note that you can use multiple [transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

```css
#rotating_image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
#rotating_image:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZKEqcWm.jpg" id="rotating_image">
```

Comment: The scale() method works exactly how I want it.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @AndreasLambadarios the other method will work if you add the transform origin.

Answer (score 1):

So this will only work if you know the start and end height... But basically height transitions have to use the max-height affect. The following example assumes you want it to grow from 100px -> 400px. Let me know if it would need to be dynamic heights

```css
#rotating_image {
                position:absolute;
                left:70px;
                top:100px;
                height: 400px;
                max-height: 100px;
                -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
                transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
                
                }

#rotating_image:hover {
                      max-height: 400px;
                      transform:rotate(360deg);
                      -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
                      -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
                      }
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZKEqcWm.jpg" id = "rotating_image">
```

Comment: this is pretty much what i'm looking for but is there a way of having it remain on a fixed axis without it moving out so much.  i.e. like a expanding windmill rotating?

Comment: @AndreasLambadarios Try [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Well no its not the rotation that is the problem, the problem actually has to do with the absolute positioning. Because that is set you will have the ending picture also having its left and top positioning set. So the top left of the image will be in the same spot. @AndreasLambadarios I assume you would want the center to stay in the same position?

Comment: @pasquers you're right.  Yea I wanted the center to stay in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can put two methods in the `transform` like this:

```css
#rotating_image {
                position:absolute;
                left:70px;
                top:100px;

                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
                transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
                
                }

#rotating_image:hover {
                      -ms-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2);
                      -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2);
                      transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2);
                      }
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZKEqcWm.jpg" id = "rotating_image">
```

The 2's in the `scale()` are just examples. You can use different numbers. `scale()` multiplies by the numbers in the parameter: first is the width, second is the height. Also, the properties with the prefixes should always come before the properties without them. Example to explain previous sentence: `-webkit-transform` and `-ms-transform` should come before `transform`.

Comment: This is dope feedback and a simple explanation of the scale(). thanks.